# How to storeimage from input in mobx-state-tree model?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am trying to find a solution how I can store files in mobx-state-tree models.
But mobx-state-tree don't have something like `types.file`.
Does anyone know how to deal with this kind of problem?
Or I have to find another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone still wonders how to deal with input `type="file"` data, I ended up using `volatile` on my form model:

```js
const EditForm = types
  .model({ /*...*/ })
  .volatile(() => ({
    pictureFile: null
  }))
  .actions(self => ({
    setPicture(file) {
      self.pictureFile = file;
    },
    save: flow(function*() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('picture', self.picture);
      // ...
    })
  }))
```

In your change handler of the file input:

```js
onFileInputChange(e) {
  editFormStore.setPicture(e.target.files[0])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question, but I think you are trying to use MST for more than what it is supposed to do. Generally, MST is for storing the state of your app and if I understood your question correctly, the actual contents of your files should not be part of the app state.

What I normally do for handling files is to make models that store the file's info (name, size, ext, path, etc.) then retrieve the file when you actually need to use it.